# Is the following sentence grammatically correct? (parallel structure)

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions

The sentence is the following,

> In developing countries, the investment by multinational enterprises
> has led to the rapid development of industry and commerce, increased
> employment opportunities, and increased the income of the urban
> population.

Does the sentence lead to confusion? Thank you.

Comment: "... investment by multinational enterprises has [led to the rapid development of industry and commerce], [increased employment opportunities], [and increased the income of the urban population]". The bracketed items are a coordination of verb phrases functioning as complement of "has".

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would note in addition to the above analyses - the sentence could also be interpreted as such:

In developing countries, the investment by multinational enterprises has led to:

1. the rapid development of industry and commerce
2. increased employment opportunities
3. increased the income of the urban population -- *this part wouldn't be grammatically correct - "the investment has led to increased the income of the urban population".*

If you wanted to avoid any misinterpretation here, you could add in 'has', as follows:

> In developing countries, the investment by multinational enterprises has led to the rapid development of industry and commerce, increased employment and **has** increased the income of the urban population.

Answer (score 0):

> In developing countries, the investment by multinational enterprises has [led to the rapid development of industry and commerce], [increased employment opportunities], and [increased the income of the urban population]."

The example is fine as BillJ has demonstrated in his parsing.